# MapInfo SQL Query with Metacharacters?

Tags: sql, mapinfo, query, select, regular-expression

I have +8 million edge in MapInfo. I want to select character+digit but I can't.

I tried querying as [a-z]+[0-9] but failed to use metacharacters in MapInfo.

"New York 1. Street" is true.
"New York1. Street" is false. I want to select this.

How can I reach the solution?

Comment: What exact query are you using and from where/what dialog?

Comment: I use query window or mapbasic window. my query as ROAD_NAME like "%[a-z][0-9]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking to use Regex in your expression.

There are a few ways to do this depending on your version of MapInfo Pro:

- v2021: Has built-in support for Regex via some new MapBasic functions, see the [MapBasic v2021 post](https://community.precisely.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=67&MessageKey=5e300fbe-a2ff-457f-bd48-97f297b431ce) on the Precisely Knowledge Community
- v17 or newer: You can use the WindowHelper tool that can be found [on the MapInfo Marketplace](http://mapinfomarketplace.precisely.com/product/cb1da1fc-a1f3-4bb6-aa40-e6c426738188). It has a number of custom functions that are published into MapInfo Pro
- Old 32 bit versions: You can use the [mbRegex from North Road](https://north-road.com/2013/05/05/regular-expressions-in-mapbasic/) but only through a compiled MapBasic application